# PrincipalPermission vs. web.config for page access controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web-config

I currently have my access permissions in `web.config`:

```
 <location path="Account">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
 </location>
 ...
```

I don't like this for two reasons:

1. `web.config` becomes a mess as my website builds up
2. I'm not sure it's good security to keep the web page access rule so separated from the page itself. After all, I edit aspx/c# files most of the day and not web.config, so things tend to slip.
3. This is a very weird one... I just added ASP.NET4 routing, which changes the URLs. So, all of a sudden my web.config permissions are no longer valid! Similar to point #2 above.

I was thinking it would be better to just use PrincipalPermission as security attributes for the classes/c# files involved in each aspx. My question:

- Is this done by anyone, or is it a bad ideas?
- More importantly... My PrincipalPermission attribute generates an exception (good) but does not redirect users back to the logon page (bad). Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I know one trick that might be usefull - if you put your pages in separated folders you can have a local web.config per folder. No includes in global web config required.
See 'ASP.NET application subdirectory' row of table in 'Scope of Configuration Settings' section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Principal permissions seem like a good idea on the surface. But, having been down that route, the trade-offs become far, far uglier than any massive amount of configuration you might get out of using "normal" security methods. The biggest drawback, IMHO, is that they lay a minefield of potential exceptions for whoever comes behind you needs to work around. All your security becomes quite hardcoded as they are compile-time attributes so you can't easily mate them to runtime configuration settings. And what happens to those real world scenarios where there are exceptions to every rule?

Anyhow, if you must go that way, your best friend is going to be a custom IPrincipal implementation to work around alot of the PrincipalPermissionAttribute imposed constraints.

Comment: What do you mean security becomes quite hardcoded? That you can't change it without recompiling?

Answer (score 0):

I just posted an answer on another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16156169/976973).

I did not want to use web.config for authorization so I came up with a MVC like implementation using an Attribute and a custom Principal.