# Secure Login Or Login check in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication, webforms

I am new in asp, here my question is that i have a website with pages home, about, contact, and `login`. In this website user can `login` and then access the home page, on home page there is a grid view with master page. The problem is that user can access the home page without `login`, just edit the path in address bar. For example
the `login` page path is

```
http://lolhost:54515/mastergridvie/Login.aspx
```

and user edit it

```
http://localhost:54515/mastergridvie/Home.aspx
```

so user can go on home page without login, How I can prevent this?

I know for this there use a session, but I have no idea how to and where create a session for this :(
Please can anyone help me?

Comment: Use `Authorize` attribute on your `HomeController`

Comment: Can u guide me how i can use these controller ? Please.

Comment: @wudzik she is using webforms so she wouldn't have a home controller.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217576/is-there-an-authorizeattribute-equivalent-to-just-standard-web-forms-not-mvc-f

Comment: yes i am useing webforms with master page

Comment: @DiamondHearts your best best is to use codproject.com and run through a few tutorials on Webforms or ASP.NET MVC. The first option is much quicker, but the second option will help you learn the fundamentals for web-development much better. Not to mention the latter is the future. MVC would be more beneficial for your long-term develoment as a web-developer and the long tail maintenance of your website, but the webforms will deliver your product quicker if you have a background in .net winforms desktop development.

Answer (score 3):

Create Session in login page like this.

```
Session["userid"]="something";
```

And After That Check in Every Page Load like This.

```
if(Session["userid"] == null)
{
  Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: This is similar to what I was going to post, although cookie-less session authentication isn't the most widely accepted method for webform authentication.