# Admin access to page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a website, It does not have Member System but it has Admin page that i want only Admins allowed to access, I have created login panel for Admins and when typing a certain password they are Redirected to the Admin Default Page, The problem is when anyone type the path of the admin page he can access it without logging in

Comment: I wish you all the best with your endevour. When you encounter a _specific_ question, feel free to ask it. What you can't expect though is that we do the coding for you.

Comment: I just don't even know how to make it, I want to know the idea, didn't ask for any code btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create `Session`. 
You can find your solution here [Secure Login Or Login check in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854629/secure-login-or-login-check-in-asp-net)

Hope this might help you

Comment: You can customize through web. Config

Comment: Thanks it helped <3

Comment: If this solution helps you please mark answer as accepted

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper how to customize through web config? :3

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config

Comment: @RaviMatani It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that only admins can access the page you specify, try saving a variable in the users session as a 'cookie'. There should be enough examples to be found on stackoverflow!

Comment: I think it will not be that effective i want to avoid any bugs or any hackers access the admin panel