# Use Authorize Attribute to Verify Identity User Logged In

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm creating a new ASP.NET web application and I'm not planning on making use of the concept of "roles". I do, however, want to make sure a user is logged in on certain pages. Is there any existing attribute that simply checks if a user is logged in and redirects them or throws an error if they're not? Every search I've done points to using roles (such as [this one](http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/11/asp-net-identity-2-1-roles-based-authorization-authentication-asp-net-web-api/)).

Comment: Decorating an action with the `[Authorize]` attribute will only return successfully when the user is logged in. There's also `Request.IsAuthenticated`

Comment: you could also add the [Authorize] attribute to the whole class.

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095889/mvc-authentication-easiest-way/32096289#32096289

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `[Authorize]` attribute will only return successfully if the user initiating the request is logged in and will only work on controllers and action methods.

It can be used to decorate a particular action:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    // only FooAction requires authentication in FooController
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> FooAction()
    {        

    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> BarAction()
    {

    }
}
```

...or an entire controller:

```
// all actions in FooController require authentication
[Authorize]
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> FooAction()
    {        

    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> BarAction()
    {

    }
}
```

You also have `Request.IsAuthenticated` which can be used on both action and non-action methods:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated) //or @if in Razor
{
    //request is authenticated 
}
```

...and even `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` as @Darko correctly pointed out in his answer. Personally, I prefer `Request.IsAuthenticated` over `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` as it also provides some useful null-checks for `User` and `User.Identity`. Here's how `Request.IsAuthenticated` looks under the hood:

```
public bool IsAuthenticated
{
    get
    {
        return(_context.User != null 
               && _context.User.Identity != null 
               && _context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I'll make use of each of these options.

Comment: But for aspx pages there is not attribute to check roles or authorization, like in MVC? You have to do this in code?

Comment: @FrenkyB yes, there's an `<authorization />` element you can set up in `web.config`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4217649/4302070) - you can also use `User.IsInRole("RoleName")`

Answer (score -2):

You can use User property, just put if() where it can control access and that's it.
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Page.Title = "Home page for " + User.Identity.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        Page.Title = "Home page for guest user.";
    }
}
```

This should work after you set the web.config . Here is the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wff0kyh(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Problem with your link - it talks about Forms Authentication. And Identity framework which is question is about does not use that. Though the part of code where you check `IsAuthenticated` is correct, the rest of sample is not - in MVC there is no `Page` object - you are talking about WebForms, and the question is not about WebForms.

Comment: Nothing more to add, just downvoted because it wasn't relevant to the user's question, though it's important information all the same.