# c# aspx checking session with Ajax jquery invoke

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have Ajax jquery to call c# webmethod in server-side:

```
function AjaxPostCommon(config, callBack) {
    const request = $.ajax({
        url: config.Url,
        type: "POST",
        data: config.Data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: config.BeforeSend,
        statusCode: {
            404: function () {
                console.log("page not found");
            }
        }
    })
        .done(function (response) {
            callBack(response);
        })
        .fail(function (xhr) {
            console.log(config.Url + "\n" + xhr.statusText);
        })
        .always(config.Always);

    return request;
}
```

and `my.aspx.cs` class, some functions like these:

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static dynamic HasTextures(StyleModel styleModel)
        {
            try
            {
                var userId = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"];
                if (userId == null) return new { error = "-1" };


                bool result = checkSomething();

                return new { data = result };
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.LogException(e, GetUserId(), "PDC", "HasTextures");
                return new { error = e.Message };
            }
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static dynamic DeleteDesignFile(StyleModel styleModel)
        {
            try
            {
                var userId = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"];
                if (userId == null) return new { error = "-1" };

                return new { data = false };
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.LogException(e, GetUserId(), "PDC", "HasTextures");
                return new { error = e.Message };
            }
        }
```

I'm checking session like what I did in code below.
I'll get value in `callBack` of Jquery. If error = -1, I will redirect to Login page.
Are there a better way to check session? and reduce lines of code:

```
var userId = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"];
if (userId == null) return new { error = "-1" };
```

I thought about `Attribute` and did research. Can apply here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there an authorizeattribute equivalent to just standard web forms (not MVC) for .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217576/is-there-an-authorizeattribute-equivalent-to-just-standard-web-forms-not-mvc-f)

Comment: @Hintham I took a look. I cannot figure out it's similar that question.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it doesn't completely cover your question. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Modify your web.config to include something like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="index.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
```

The above will ensure that a user is redirected to your login page if he or she hasn't been authenticated. And then in your code you can use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to check if a user is authenticated.